# Ajax rendered button is not firing click event

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, dom

I have a Django template that lists scheduled classes for our training department. For each item in the list there is a roster button that when clicked pulls the class roster for the class and places it into a div. That works fine. On this page there is also a Javascript date control that allows the user to select a class date and see just classes being held on that day. However, the `Roster` button click event does not fire when the class list is generated from Ajax.

classes.html

```
<h1>Upcoming Classes</h1>
Class Date: <input type='text' id='datepicker' name='date'/>
<div id='class_listing'>
<ul id='class_list'>
{% if classes %}
{% for c in classes %}
<li>
    <div class='class_info'>
        <ul class='class_list_item'>
            <li>
                <h4>
                    <a href="{% url 'training:class_detail' c.id %}">
                        {{ c.course.course_name }}
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h6>
                    Start Date: {{ c.get_start_date }}
                </h6>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h5>{{ c.location }}</h5>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class='list_button' value='{{ c.id }}'>Roster</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
 <div class='roster'></div>
<div class='button_menu'><button>Test</button></div>
</div>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No classes available</p>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

This works. However, when I process the selected date and generate a list of classes for that date the roster button does not work.

My view:

```
def getclasslisting(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        date = request.GET['date']
        month, day, year = date.split('/')
        formatted_date = year + '-' + month + '-' + day
        schedule = Schedule.objects.filter(class_date=formatted_date)
        if not schedule:
            html = '<h4>No classes scheduled on ' + formatted_date + '</h4>'
        else:
            html = "<ul id='class_list'>"
            for s in schedule: 
                html += "<li><div class='class_info'><ul class='class_list_item'>"

                html += "<li><h4><a href='#'>" + s.scheduled_class.course.course_name + "</a></h4></li>"

                html += "<li><h6>Start Date: " + s.scheduled_class.get_start_date() + "</h6></li>"

                html += "<li><h5>" + s.scheduled_class.location.name + "</h5></li>"

                html += "<li><button class='list_button' value='" + str(s.scheduled_class.id) + "'>Roster</button></li></ul>"

                html += "<div class='roster'></div><div class='button_menu'></div></div></li></ul>"

    else:
        pass
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Finally, the javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#toggle').click(buildMenu);
$('.list_button').click(getRoster);
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
        $.get('/training/getclasslisting', {date:date}, function(data){
            $('#class_listing').empty();
            $('#class_listing').append(data);
        });
        //alert("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + date);
    }
});
})

function getRoster() {
var roster = $(this).closest("ul").next();
var id = parseInt(this.value);
$.get('/training/getroster', { id:id}, function(data){
    if (roster.is(':empty')) {
        roster.append(data);
    } else {   
        roster.empty();
    }
    alert("Clicked!");
});
}
```

I thought initially it was a difference in the DOM between the HTML page, which works, and the javascript, which doesn't, but I have checked it. Also I added the `alert` statement to the javascript to see if the function gets called and it isn't. Any ideas? I have resigned myself to the fact that it is a stupid oversight on my part.

Comment: Use `.on()` instead of `.click()` in your JavaScript, [see here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work. Do I need to use an anon function? Wouldn't think so but javascript/jquery is not really my thing. It still works in the template though so I will use `on`.

Comment: Probably not related, but please don't build up HTML in the view. You're happily using templates elsewhere, what makes you think it's a good idea to do it in Python for that view?

Comment: I will not put it into production that way, this was just a quick way for me to get the Ajax built. It may seem convoluted to some but because my javascript skills are somewhat lacking I want to get the Ajax right first. Once that is good, rest assured I will change the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$('body').on('click', '.list_button', function(){
....
});
```

However it is a client-side problem.

Comment: Worked like a champ. Any idea why using `$('.list_button').on("click", getRoster);` didn't?

Comment: because when you inject some HTML in your page with ajax you have to rebind the events. 
You can do it in the callback of your ajax function or better using on() that does just that.